# Preventing instantiation of an internal class used in its outer class from a third, external class

Tags: c#, instantiation, inner-classes

With the following structure:

```
public class OuterClass {
   public InnerClass foo {get; private set}
   public OuterClass() {
      foo = new InnerClass()
   }
   public class InnerClass {
      sometype somevar;
      public InnerClass()
   }
}
```

How is access to the inner class constructor restricted from a third class as so:

```
OuterClass outerclassinstance = new OuterClass();
outerclassinstance.foo.somevar; // allowed
OuterClass.Innerclass innerclassinstance = new Outerclass.InnerClass(); // not allowed
innerclassinstance.somevar // not allowed
```

If I make InnerClass private I get an Inconsistent accessibility error for 'foo', and if I make foo private as well it naturally can't be accessed from a third class.

Is it even possible or should I be looking for an entirely different solution entirely? Is there a structural design pattern that resolves this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
public interface IInnerClass {
}

public class OuterClass {
   public IInnerClass foo {get; private set;}
   public OuterClass() {
      foo = new InnerClass();
   }
   private class InnerClass : IInnerClass {
      sometype somevar;
      public InnerClass(){}
   }
}
```

Your InnerClass is private, but you can have a public interface to it.

Comment: This has the desired functionality other than 'somevar' not being accessible through the third, external class.
   new OuterClass().foo.somevar // IInnerClass does not contain a definition for 'somevar'.
This is, unless somevar is included within the interface. Must it be included in the interface, then?

Comment: You can put in the interface declaration anything you wish to expose to outside. Of course you have to implement the interface in InnerClass accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This may be Helpful :

```
public class OuterClass {
   public InnerClass foo {get; private set}
   public OuterClass() {
      foo = new InnerClass()
   }
   public class InnerClass {
      protected sometype somevar;
      protected InnerClass()
   }
}
```

Comment: The protected keyword plays a role in inheritance. There is no such thing here.

Comment: protected keyword is access spacifier and its use in Inheritance.

Comment: You cannot even use a protected InnerClass constructor with your example.

Comment: why ? protected allows access to only its child class instance.

Comment: Did you put the code in VS, or just speculate here? I did.

Comment: outerclassinstance.foo.somevar; may be not access by making InnerClass private